# Rebase two remote branches without write permission

Tags: git

I am porting code to a new server while other members of my team keep working off of the main develop branch.

```
blessed/develop <- ongoing work here
blessed/newserver <- port team here
myfork/newserver <- my fork on the port team branch
```

I have made two pull requests, and the main team has made three

```
blessed/develop -A-B-C
blessed/newserver -D-E
```

I want to rebase the `blessed/develop` onto the `blessed/newserver` so I can work off of the latest code.

```
blessed/newserver -A-B-C-D-E
```

I can do it on my fork locally like so, however I don't have write permission to force push it up to `blessed/newserver`

```
git pull --rebase blessed develop
*resolve conflicts*
git push -f myfork newserver

Output:
blessed/develop -A-B-C
blessed/newserver -D-E
myfork/newserver -A-B-C-D-E

Desired:
blessed/develop -A-B-C
blessed/newserver -A-B-C-D-E
myfork/newserver -A-B-C-D-E
```

If I try to make a pull request from `myfork/newserver`, D-E have different hashes, and I'm afraid of this happening:

```
blessed/newserver -D-E-A-B-C-D-E
```

Is there a way for me to fix this without write permission? Should I just make my pull request and have the repo owner rebase the extra commits? Whats the best way for me to keep up with the latest code while not tearing my head off with rebasing (we are ff-only).

Comment: Why not merge `develop` onto `newserver`? It would be a compatible push.

Answer (score 0):

You have write permissions, you don't have force push permissions, which is done to prevent you from making `git pull` too painful for other users.

So you can't convert it to

```
blessed/newserver -A-B-C-D-E
```

What you should go with is,

```
blessed/newserver -D-E-A-B-C
```

This can be done in following steps:

1. reset `myfork/newserver` to correct hash of `E` . One way to get hash is run a `git log blessed/newserver` if you didn't modify it. Or you can see on github.
2. cherrypick commits from `blessed/develop` to `myfork/newserver` . On `myfork/newserver` run `git cherry-pick A^..C`.
3. Force push `myfork/newserver` . This you can, and will fix your PR.